# Bought custom navigation menu from codecanyon, how to change feature.php?

Tags: menus, css

I bought a nav-menu with css but not sure how to use this in my wordpress theme. Is there a standard way to implement it?

Like this question:http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32186/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-navigation-menu-with-the-code

Documentation that came with the navmenu:
is this: http://www.hicengineering.com/navmenu.html

Comment: It's hard to say how the author of the code needs you to use the code without actually seeing it. Did the author supply a documentation that you can refer to?

Comment: It probably would be best to contact the author of the plugin for support. As Daniel said it is hard to determine what to do without seeing the code that the plugin uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I understand you want to implement a custom menu in your wordpress theme.

First of all you have to understand the template structure of the theme you're using. Most themes have the navigation menu in the header.php or templates/head.php, it depends.

Additionally, will you use a static menu or dynamic? Dynamic meaning you're adding the pages (created via wordpress dashboard) automatically in the navigation menu structure. Static is just a copy paste operation of the nav-menu.

Lastly, the author of the nav-menu you've purchased is using wordpress as well. It may be worth asking him for advice.

Hope it helps you moving forward.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  I'm going to be using a dynamic menu system... I'll have a look at the header.php again.